# Finding out how much additional physical memory a process is using in linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, centos6

I am trying to figure out how much memory a program requires. I need to run multiple instances of this program and I want to figure out how much additional RAM I need. I did some research and to find the amount of memory used I did: top, which gave me the following

```
Mem:  32880876k total,  7573308k used, 25307568k free,   192956k buffers
Swap:  8241148k total,        0k used,  8241148k free,  4800560k cached

PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
27464 root      20   0 3107m 1.9g  19m S 99.6  6.0   0:37.78 krypton
```

RES, if I understood correctly is the resident memory which is the amount of memory that resides in the actual RAM. When I ran 2 instances of the program i noticed that the RES field for both were at around 5Gb each but the total memory used (shown at the top) did not go up by 10Gb as I had expected, but instead went up by less than 1Gb.

I did some research on this and found out that RES also includes shared memory. Using the same scenario as above, I noticed the shared memory SHR was at around 4.7Gb for each. So performing a simple subtraction yields around 0.3Gb, so does that mean that when I run 2 instances of my program that I need 4.7Gb+(0.3Gb)*2=5.3Gb of RAM? Also does the SHR memory include virtual memory as well?

If so, do I need to subtract the VIRT from SHR to find out the amount of memory which comes from the RAM? If this memory usage were to go up linearly, would running 20 instances take 4.7Gb+(0.3Gb)*20=10.7Gb of RAM?

Comment: Ignore VIRT, RES, SHR and every other process metric. Look at the global used memory value (the top line). Run one instance, notice the value. Run two instances, notice the value. Continue for another couple of iterations. Plot a graph. Extrapolate.

Answer (score 0):

You want to inspect /proc/pid/smaps. Run 2 instances and then look for Private_* fields.